# Unable to split an edge as expected

Tags: modeling, edges

I have selected one edge and would like to split it. When I click on the command in the menu, nothing happens. When I use the modifier, nothing happens. My selection on the object remains.

I am definitely in edge mode.
It is definitely selected and it is the only selected edge/face/vertex/object.
No UVs.
Shading: nothing selected, neither smooth nor sharp for anything.

I'm pretty new to Blender, so I apologize if this is silly/dumb.

This does not work:
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?279119-Edge-Split-Not-Working

Stats:
Blender 2.71
17" MacBook Pro from mid 2009
OSX version 10.7.5 (lion)
8 GB of RAM
NVIDIA GeForce 9400 M 256 MB
2.66 GHz Intel Core Duo Pro

Comment: Is the title of the question connected to the content? They seem to be about different things.

Comment: What do you mean by `the command in the menu`?  What command are you using?  What do you mean by `split it`?  Do you mean that you want to divide an edge into two?  Have you tried using subdivide?

Comment: If you only want to split an edge into two parts, phrase it like this "How to split an edge into two parts" and your question will work. The term edge split is already used for something different you might not know yet. See also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19131/how-to-properly-use-face-smooth-shading/19142#19142 Besides that it is always a good idea to explain what you expected.

Comment: I was trying to split it, using "Edge Split". "Edge Subdivide" does what I was looking for.
Chris, you got it right, thank you.

By "the command in the menu" I meant <press "space" to bring up the menu of commands and click "Edge Split", sorry for the confusion there.

Edge Split still seemed to do nothing. However "Edge Split" can only be seen in the rendering screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly, since the topic asks something else than the text. If I got it right, you want to know why you can not split a single selected edge.

I think the problem is that Blender can not connect two vertices with an edge twice.

If you only select one edge and try to split it, Blender would have to insert a second edge between its two vertices. My guess is that this collides with the internal data structure of Blender.

To solve this problem you would have to insert another vertex along this edge first, so that after splitting you will get a "ring" of four edges. Then there are no two vertices connect twice and Blender is happy.

Comment: Wait... so splitting an edge is NOT how you insert a new vertex? -- I don't see an insert vertex command, so how can I split one edge into two edges?