# Edge Split disconnecting the edge

Tags: modeling, modifiers, rigging, edges

I have modelled the following head in Blender 2.90.1:
[image]

The only modifier on this model is the edge split modifier (30° and Sharp Edges)
When i apply the modifier, the edges get disconnected which is subotimal for the rigging process:
[image]

If i discard the modifier, the mesh looses quality:
[image]

I tried to mark all disconnected edges with sharp edges and merge them by distance, which didn't improve the problem. Does anyone know a good fix to use the edge split mod without loosing the quality and without disconnecting the edges? Would be great, because I used this mod on almost 70% of the whole character. Changing them all by hand would be terrible.

Comment: Have you tried [auto smooth](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38616/5705)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  That's what an edge split modifier does.  If you don't want to disconnect the edges, don't use an edge split modifier.  If you're trying to use an edge split modifier to create hard edges, there are other techniques (mark sharp, autosmooth, which it appears you're already using); if you need an edge split modifier for an export somewhere, don't apply it until after you weight, if it's screwing you up.

Comment: Okay thank you for your answer. I'd guess I won't use the modifier any more.

One alternative which works "ok" but not perfect for me is to change the edge split modifier to a bevel modifier with the same angle limit. 
Disadventage of this is the face-count, but I think i have to take this in the end.